# How can I receive emails in C++ via POP3?

Tags: c++, .net, email, pop3

I've been trying to find a POP3 C++ client on the internet but I haven't found any luck.

We are working on a project for school that is essentially a C++ course (so I can't use C#...), and we are making a Email client that has to support sending and receiving emails and attachments. We are also working with .NET (because apparently MFC is terrible, although I haven't used it, anyone have an opinion on this?), and so I would prefer a Microsoft built in library solution to this. So far we've been able to get sending of email working using SMPTclient, but no POP3 luck.

If anyone has a solution in .NET that would be great, otherwise I'll have to write my own POP3 client code, and if anyone has a link for that to get me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, MFC is, in fact, terrible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[POCO](http://pocoproject.org/) has POP3- and SMTP-support in its Net-library.

Comment: I don't think I can use any libraries that aren't built in... If I can convince my prof then this will be perfect ;) And I don't have enough rep to upvote this but when I do I will!

Comment: Does he want you to write the Pop3Client yourself? If not there shouldn't be anything wrong with using libraries for functionality win32/.NET doesn't offer. Btw, for .NET you could take a look at e.g. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/despop3client.aspx

Comment: Yes, SHE ;) does want us to write it our self if its not part of the standard library. The source code on the one you just posted might work though, seems not as intense as POP :)

Answer (score 1):

I've written SMTP e-mail sending code using COM-CDO (on Windows); for getting email (POP3)
I condensed the following code snippet as a watered-down example. If your POP3 server uses
TLS/SSL, your hosed without 3rd-party software - you have to implement SSL and the code would
probably take years to develop. I second the use of POCO. Here's what I have for non-SSL
(sorry for any Z DIrectory calls, it should be easy to figure out):

```
#include <winsock2.h>

#define MAX_MSG         40000                   // max message length
#define COMM_SUFF       "\r\n"
#define COMM_USER       "USER "
#define COMM_PASS       "PASS "
#define COMM_STAT       "STAT\r\n"
#define COMM_LIST       "LIST\r\n"
#define COMM_QUIT       "QUIT\r\n"
#define COMM_RETR       "RETR "
#define COMM_TOP        "TOP "
#define COMM_DELETE     "DELE "
#define COMM_NOOP       "NOOP\r\n"

SOCKET sock_no;                             // SOCKET no
struct sockaddr_in sok = {0};               // SOCKET struct
struct hostent *hp;
string_o command, s, msg_num;
string_o user = "EMAIL_USERNAME";
string_o passw = "EMAIL_PASSWORD";
char buff[MAX_MSG];                         // pop-3 output buffer
sock_no = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); // init socket
sok.sin_family = AF_INET;
int n_bytes = 0;                            // num of return bytes

s = "gorth@Vettrasoft.com";
hp = gethostbyname(s.data());             // get server IP address
if (hp != NULL)
    bcopy ((u_char *) &sok.sin_addr, (const u_char *) hp->h_addr, hp->h_length);
else
    return -1;

sok.sin_port = (unsigned short int) htons(110);

//..........................................................
// connect to pop-3 server and logon
//..........................................................
if (::connect(sock_no, (sockaddr *) &sok, sizeof (sockaddr_in)) != 0)
    return -1;

n_bytes = ::recv (sock_no, buff, MAX_MSG, 0); // skip first server answer

// send "user" command
command = COMM_USER + user + COMM_SUFF;
n_bytes = ::send (sock_no, command.data(), command.size(), 0);

// get server answer
n_bytes = ::recv (sock_no, buff, MAX_MSG, 0);

// send PASS command
command = COMM_PASS + passw + COMM_SUFF;
n_bytes = ::send (sock_no, command.data(), command.size(), 0);

n_bytes = ::recv (sock_no, buff, MAX_MSG, 0); // get server answer

//..........................................................
// get list of messages; get number of messages in inbox
//..........................................................
command = COMM_STAT;
n_bytes = ::send (sock_no, command.data(), command.size(), 0);
n_bytes = ::recv (sock_no, buff, MAX_MSG, 0);

// extract number of messages
msg_num = get_field(buff, "+OK ");
pos = msg_num.find(' ', &ie);
msg_num = msg_num.substring(0, pos);
count = ::z_str_to_int (msg_num.data());

//..........................................................
// do all messages from list. # of messages begins from 1
//..........................................................
for (i = 1; i <= count && !ie; i++)
    ie = process_nextmail (sock_no, i, buff, do_kill);

//..........................................................
// quit and disconnect pop-3 server; send "QUIT" command
//..........................................................
command = COMM_QUIT;
n_bytes = ::send (sock_no, command.data(), command.size(), 0);
return ::closesocket(sock_no);
```